# BufferedImage goes black when used as method parmeter

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I've got what seems like a very simple section of code, and I can't work out for the life of me why it's not working.

I have a method that listens for image updates from a camera and when it recieves them it calls another segment of code.

My listener is:

```
public void imageUpdated(BufferedImage image) {
    if (null != video) {   
        video.setImage(image);
    }
    File outputfile = new File("savedingui.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Which happily saves the correct image to disc. However when I save the image again from the setImage method (called on line 3 of the listener code)

```
public void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
    File outputfile = new File("savedorig.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It now just saves a jpeg of black. But the right sized square of black.

Any clues as to whats going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not reproduce your issue with the following source (which is basically copied from your question):

```
public static void imageUpdated(BufferedImage image) {
    setImage(image);

    File outputfile = new File("savedingui.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void setImage(BufferedImage image) {
    File outputfile = new File("savedorig.jpg");
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", outputfile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("test.jpg"));
    imageUpdated(image);
}
```

Is the same instance used somewhere else, e.g. camera writing updated data in it?

Comment: This was one of those very rare issues where a restart has fixed things. I'm using the Xuggler library for my video so I'm pinning it on that as that uses a lot of native code and not just Java code.

Comment: Glad that it's solved for you. From what I read in the documentation, Xuggler can copy data directly to an IVideoPicture. So if you used the toImage() method, the BufferedImage probably relied on the exact same buffer, Xuggler wrote to. Just assumptions though, since I don't know Xuggler very well.